# How to change video drivers from the CLI

Tags: command-line, drivers, nvidia, xserver, gpu-driver

I've read a few things but can't get a definitive answer.

So to confirm, is it

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt-get install nvidia-381
```

and then to switch back, it would be simply

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

So just to clarify, to switch to the video drivers you want, you're essentially installing them rather than just enabling them?

Answer (score 1):

Yes `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340` would be how you switch to the Nvidia-340 driver. Basically you're installing the drivers like software and the old driver is automatically uninstalled.